# View flicking while hiding/showing on scroll in recycler view

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, show-hide

I have linear layout at the bottom and I want to hide that view on scroll up and show on scroll down. I was able to achieve that with scroll listener on recycler view .  But there is one problem, when you are scrolling slow view is flickering  (showing and hiding fast).

This is my code

```
bottom = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.linerabottom);
    recycleList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0) {
                bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
```

Here is a video of the issue https://goo.gl/photos/TwUJjmPUA4kJCsaR8 .

Can you help me to find out what is the issue ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, because your `dy` at some point of time fluctuates between `dy >= 0` and `dy < 0`. If you want to achieve sort of quick return view, you should bound it to something like this:

```
 recycleList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            mTotalDy += dy;
            if (dy > 0 && mTotalDy >= bottom.getHeight()) {
                bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else if(recyclerView.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && bottom.getVisiblity() == View.GONE) {
                bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTotalDy = 0;
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation , your code works like a charm , I just changed RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE to RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING because view was not showing up on scroll up (I thing scroll up/down is dragging state ) .